# Spread operator no longer passed in React Native map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After upgrading to React 16.8 and React Native 0.59.8, using the spread operator inside a jsx map function no longer works.

Old no-longer working code:

```
this.orders.map(function (order, idx) {
   return <Row key={idx} {...order} />
});
```

Row no longer receives 'order' object.

New working code:

```
this.orders.map(function (order, idx) {
   return <Row key={idx} order={order} />
});
```

Row receives 'order'.

Am I missing something fundamental (most possibly as I've been at it for hours) or is there a change?

Updated:

```
this.state.orders.map(function (order, idx) {
                            return <Row key={idx} {...order} showModalOrderDetails={this.showModalOrderDetails} getOrders={this.getOrders} />
                        }.bind(this))
```

Results:

05-14 16:04:24.365 29691 29971 I ReactNativeJS: **'Props received in child:'**, { showModalOrderDetails: [Function: bound proxiedMethod],

05-14 16:04:24.365 29691 29971 I ReactNativeJS:   getOrders: [Function: bound proxiedMethod] }

**05-14 16:04:24.467 29691 29971 E ReactNativeJS: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.customer.firstname')**

Whilst:

```
 this.state.orders.map(function (order, idx) {
                            return <Row key={idx} order={order} showModalOrderDetails={this.showModalOrderDetails} getOrders={this.getOrders} />
                        }.bind(this))
```

Results:

05-14 16:08:42.033 29691 29971 I ReactNativeJS: **'Props received in child:'**, { order:

05-14 16:08:42.033 29691 29971 I ReactNativeJS:    { id: 2132,

05-14 16:08:42.033 29691 29971 I ReactNativeJS:      customerOrderId: 123,

05-14 16:08:42.033 29691 29971 I ReactNativeJS:      franchiseId: 41,

05-14 16:08:42.033 29691 29971 I ReactNativeJS:      customer:

05-14 16:08:42.033 29691 29971 I ReactNativeJS:       **{ firstname: 'erich',**

...
05-14 16:08:42.033 29691 29971 I ReactNativeJS:   showModalOrderDetails: [Function: bound proxiedMethod],

05-14 16:08:42.033 29691 29971 I ReactNativeJS:   getOrders: [Function: bound proxiedMethod] }

**UPDATED**

It is solved if I do the following:

```
this.state.orders.map(function (order, idx) {
                            let norder = {
                                ...order, 
                                showModalOrderDetails: this.showModalOrderDetails,
                                getOrders: this.getOrders
                            }
                            return <Row key={idx} {...norder}  />
                        }.bind(this))
```

Can someone explain that? I've never had to do that previously.

Comment: What is the data type of `order`? If it's an object, then `{...order}` should be fine, if it's a simple value (e.g. a number or string) then you should use `order={order}`. In other words, it depends on *how* you want to pass the `order` to `Row`.

Comment: The spread operator should have no effect on what version of React your running.  The spread operator is Javascript, not React.

Comment: it's because you're spreading the elements in the object.  for example if it's order: { name: 1 } you'e putting `name` as the prop - not `order`.  My answer below is correct i don't know why it got downvoted.

Comment: Updated with a working solution. Not sure why though?

Comment: Yeah why do we have to do that? It works but... it's nonsense having to change it for the whole app :/

Answer (score 2):

The spread as an attribute in this case is usually done to pass a set of object keys down as props, rather than an object itself. For example, consider this object:

```
const obj = {
  propA: 5,
  propB: 'hi'
}
```

If you spread this: `<MyComp {...obj}/>`, it is the same as doing: `<MyComp propA={obj.propA} propB={obj.propB}/>`

So with that said, if the object you are spreading contains a key `order` (so `order.order` is valid), then spreading **will** put an order prop on the component. For example:

```
const order = {
  order: 'something'
}

<MyComp {...order}/> // this will pass a prop called order down
```

So if your original code worked at one stage, I suspect you had an `order` key on your object. You can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Comment: Yeah, be nice if people said why.. :(   But currently it's not really answering why -> `After upgrading : no longer works`.   Upgrading React should have zero effect on how the spread operator works, older versions of React would be the same,.. I've a feeling the OP is seeing something else, and it just happened to be a problem after upgrading, potentially lots of other stuff...

Comment: @Keith Well I believe it is answering why. Versions would not effect the syntax, so the only logical answer is that something else has changed, likely that data itself (and that the prior data only worked because it had an order key).

Comment: Yes, your edit came after reading your post.  btw.  Wasn't me who down-voted, just giving a reason why somebody might have.  I'll upvote anyway, as your edit I suspect is the reason..  IOW: what's been passed to order, is not what was passed before..

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I agree that {...order} will be this.props in the child component. It is however simply not there. Obviously, something else must be wrong but it's odd because if I change it to order={order} it is available as this.props.order which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a React issue, when you use the spread operator `{...order}` the `Row` component will receive the properties inside `order`, for example if `order = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }` then `Row` receive `a`, `b` and `c` and not `order` but you can use [The destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to get the properties inside a variable `order` like this:

```
// Row.js
...
const { a, b, c } = props;
console.log(a, b, c); // 1 2 3    
// Or   
const { ...order } = props;
console.log(order); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Comment: The rest parameter syntax has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I've updated my question with debug output. It has to be something stupid on my side? Shirley?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're spreading the elements inside the object.  So for example if `order` looks like `{ id: 1, name: 'jon' }`, the `<Row />` component will have `id` and `name` as props, but not the entire order object.  If you do the below, you'll receive the order prop in the row component.  It's the same as saying `order={order}` and will work for any data type.  It's also the same as saying `{ ...{ order: order }}` - just es6 shorthand.

try this:

```
this.orders.map(function (order, idx) {
  return <Row key={idx} { ...{ order }} />
});
```

you can also simplify with ES6

```
this.orders.map((order, idx) => <Row key={idx} { ...{ order }} />)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - what should be tried and why? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: Added more clarity.  It's the correct answer @nico so not sure why it was downvoted

Comment: @johnsourcer judging from debug output you might be asking for `this.props.customer.firstName` inside of `<Row` but you're not passing that as a prop so it'll throw an error.  Unless i'm missing something.

Comment: @jsw324 the 'order' object is shown in the second debug so in the first when passing the {...order}, this.props.customer is correct. Very odd.

Comment: i don't know where/how you're getting the data but maybe the prop is `undefined` when the component first mounts and then re-renders when it receives the data.  Try simply putting a null check in so the component doesn't render if the prop is null.  I'm not sure if you tried the above, but this will work and is cleaner imho - you can destructure in the consuming component assuming it's functional `const Row = ({ customer, etc }) => (`

Comment: @NicoHaase I corrected based on your comment.  If that was the reason for the downvote, how about an upvote ;)

Comment: I've updated the question with a working solve but am not clear on why.

Comment: @jsw324  `the reason for the downvote`,  Usually the down-voters don't hang around, and explain.  I believe it's usually best to give the poster a reason, for them to have a chance to fix.  Down-voting and then running away doesn't really help SO one bit.   Personally I wound't worry about it, it costs them Rep anyway.